# How to set voice SAPI5

Tags: c++, voice, sapi

I don't realise how i can set some different voice? Yes! I read MSDN, and it didn't help

ISpVoice * pVoice = NULL, * pv1 = NULL;

```
if (FAILED(::CoInitialize(NULL)))
    return FALSE;


HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_ISpVoice, (void **)&pVoice);
if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
{
    pVoice->SetVolume(100);
    //pVoice->SetVoice();
    hr = pVoice->Speak(L"Hello papa", SPF_IS_XML, NULL);
    pVoice->Release();
    pVoice = NULL;
}
```

Comment: There's an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms719807(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: There is NO EXAMPLE how i may select my voice!

Comment: So what problem are you having with object tokens?

Comment: I don't now. My problem is that i can't select some voice, because i don't now how recognize it. If you say that is objects tokens then please help me with it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voices in SAPI are selected via [`ISpObjectToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms718134%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Typically one uses the helper function [`SpFindBestToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find the best token, and then use ISpVoice::SetVoice() to select that token:

```
ISpObjectToken* cpToken(NULL);
SpFindBestToken(SPCAT_VOICES, szRequiredAttribs, L"", &cpToken);
pVoice->SetVoice(cpToken);
cpToken->Release();
```

Now, the only issue is what you need to pass for `szRequiredAttribs`.  This needs to be a semicolon-delimited list of attributes.  The best documentation for SAPI voice attributes is in the [Object Tokens and Registry Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717036%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_Toc494873952) whitepaper, specifically, the Voices section.  There, it says that all voices must support the following attributes:

- Vendor (TTS engine Vendor name)
- Language (The LCID in hex of language this engine speaks)
- Gender (Value should be "Male" if Male voice, "Female" if female)
- VendorPreferred (If this is the Default voice for the vendor named in vendor)
- Name (String representing language independent name)

This is not an exclusive listing of attributes; other attributes may be defined by the vendor.

So, if you wanted the preferred voice from Microsoft, you would set `szRequiredAttribs = L"vendor=microsoft;vendorpreferred"`.  If you wanted a male voice (from any vendor), set `szRequiredAttribs = L"gender=male"`.